# Listening for event in Dart via JQuery "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart

I am using a Bootstrap Modal dialog in Dart via js interop. All works OK apart from listening for the custom events. I am trying to listen to the "shown" event using the following code:

```
js.scoped(() {
  js.context.jQuery("#myModal").on("shown", new js.Callback.once(() {
    print("Dialog Shown");         
  }));
});
```

However, I get the following Dart error when the event is fired:

```
Class '() => dynamic' has no instance method 'call'.\n\nNoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call'\nReceiver: Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic\nArguments: [Instance of 'Proxy']
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the callback should have one parameter ([handler parameter of `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) take a `eventObject` parameter). So your code should be :

```
js.context.jQuery("#myModal").on("shown", new js.Callback.many((eventObject) {
  print("Dialog Shown");
}));
```

Note also the use of `js.Callback.many` instead of `js.Callback.once`. The former allows the callback to be called several times.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the Bootstrap docs where the handler function is specified with no parameters.

`$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {  
  // do something
})`