# Listening for event in Dart via JQuery “on” with dart:js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dart

I use dart call bootstrap modal window,and I want register a callback function ,but found the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194291/listening-for-event-in-dart-via-jquery-on) other person mentioned before.

here is jQuery code:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function (e) {....})
```

How can I write the same code in dart with `dart:js`, because `package:js` is deprecated; so I can't use callback function .

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
...
void someCallback(e) {
  print('callback called, passed: $e');
}
...
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#myModal'])
    .callMethod('on', ['hidden.bs.modal', someCallBack]);
```

or

```
...
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#myModal'])
    .callMethod('on', ['hidden.bs.modal', (e) {
        print('callback called, passed: $e');
}]);
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use the callback directly and don't have to wrap it?

Comment: "Sure" is a strong word, it's a while I used this myself ;-)